# Overiding request.forgery_whitelisted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When a certain method is called in one of my Rails controllers I would like to check if the IP address of the user is on a trusted list, and if so override the request.forgery_whitelisted? method to be true so that CSRF protection isn't enforced.

A blog post I have read seems to suggest that declaring the following in the controller action would achieve this but it still throws a CSRF protection error.

```
if request.remote_ip = "127.0.0.1"
 def request.forgery_whitelisted?; true; end
end
```

Is there somewhere else this needs to happen in order to override the method early enough for it to take effect?

Answer (score 1):

either of the following should work:

- override/monkey-patch 'verify_authenticity_token' method in your ApplicationController:

```
def verify_authenticity_token
  super unless request.remote_ip = '127.0.0.1' # TODO: replace this with actual white-listing logic
end
```

- monkey-patch 'forgery_whitelisted?' method:

```
module ActionDispatch
  class Request
    def forgery_whitelisted?
      super if remote_ip == '127.0.0.1' # TODO: replace this with actual white-listing logic
    end
  end
end
```